# Aligning with Custom CSS & Gravity Form in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment, gravity

I can't seem to make an element move in CSS. It's a form with a background and it's centered. I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```css
#skyformbox {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  clear: both;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: #ccc url(http://www.ultraframehomeimprovements.co.uk/wp- 
 content/uploads/2018/07/Sky-box.png);
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5;
  left: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div align="left">
  <div id="skyformbox">
    [gravityform id="12" title="false" description="false"]
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you positioning 2000px left? As far as I know the "left" property will only work if the positioning is set to absolute...

Anyway try this:

```
#skyformbox {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  clear: both;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: #ccc url(http://www.ultraframehomeimprovements.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Sky-box.png);
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5;
  left: 2000px;
}
```

Setting the margin-left to 0px did the trick for me (assuming that what you're trying to do here is to get the form to align to the left side of the page).